# I would like to get Date and Time separately from DATETIME. format

Tags: sas, analytics

I would like to get only date and time separately from `01JAN13:08:29:00`

Format & Infomat available in Dataset is:

```
Date    Num     8   DATETIME.(format)   ANYDTDTM40(informat)
```

And If I run `datepart()` on `01JAN13:08:29:00` I get output as `19359` (I don't want it.)

Answer (score 2):

The `DATEPART` function extracts the date value from a datetime value.  The date value as you have seen is simply a number.  A **date format** must be applied to a variable holding a date value.  Base SAS variables have only two value types, character and numeric.

```
data want;
  now_dtm = datetime();
  now_dt = datepart(now_dtm);
  now_dt_unformatted = now_dt;

  format now_dtm datetime.;
  format now_dt date9.;  * <----- this is what you need, format stored in data set header information;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;

* you can change the format temporarily during a proc step;
proc print data=want;
  format now_dt yymmdd10.;             * <---- changes format for duration of proc step;
  format now_dt_unformatted mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually 19,359 is exactly the value you want.  You started with the number of seconds since 1960 and converted it to the number of days since 1960.

```
data x ;
  dt = '01JAN13:08:29:00'dt ;
  date = datepart(dt);
  time = timepart(dt);
  put (dt date time) (=);
run;
```

Results

```
dt=1672648140 date=19359 time=30540
```

You just need to attach a format to your new variable so that SAS will display the value in a format that humans will recognize.  You could use a format like DATE9. to have it show 19,359 as `01JAN2013`.   Similarly you need to attach a format to the time part to make it print in format that human's will interpret as a time.

```
format date date9. time time8. ;
```